# How to load the current entity object (Profile 2)

Tags: 7, entities, users

**Problem**

I'm trying to load the current entity object, in this case a profile2, profile page.

I've been using 
[Is there a way to load the current entity object?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21995/is-there-a-way-to-load-the-current-entity-object), to try and solve this. Where am I going wrong?

**So Far**

I have the following code running in a custom form inside a block. The block appears on the profile page.

```
function mymodule_form() {
    $node = menu_get_object('profile2', 1);
    dpm($node);
}
```

The path of my page is: `localhost/drupal5/profile-main/154`

I have two kinds of profile 2, machine names `main` and `school`, however the following doesn't work either.

```
$node = menu_get_object('main', 1);
```

Comment: What do you get for `arg(0)`, `arg(1)`, `arg(2)` and `arg(3)` respectively in that same function? It might just be you're picking the wrong part of the URL for the ID (your `menu_get_object()` code looks right)

Comment: I added in `$testarg = arg(1); dpm($testarg);` Add it threw back 154, so the correct number is going in, but I'm still getting nothing in $node. I guess the entity type must be wrong, but I've been digging through the module and I'm sure it's profile2. http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21profile2%21profile2.module/function/profile2_entity_info/7

Comment: What if you use [`profile2_load()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!profile2!profile2.module/function/profile2_load/7) instead? If that doesn't work then the ID (154) probably relates to the user, not the profile, so you could use [`profile2_load_by_user()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!profile2!profile2.module/function/profile2_load_by_user/7) along with `user_load()`

Comment: Ok `profile2_load` does work. But you guessed it and the UID is not equal to PID (because profiles are not created automatically) so I've used `profile2_load_by_user` with `arg(1)`, to get the correct entity. No idea why `menu_get_object` didn't work, nevermind. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get `menu_get_object` to work with profile2 so instead I used a combination of profile2_load_by_user and arg suggested by Clive.

```
function mymodule_form() {
   //this arg gets the UID from the URL.
    $testarg = arg(1);

  //The UID is then put into a profile2 defined function which locates and opens the
  //correct profile.
    $currentprofile = profile2_load_by_user($testarg);
}
```